# Vimeo App to allow end users to upload to the owner's account via API

Tags: javascript, php, api, vimeo

We are building an application based on Vimeo, where we would have one main account to hold all the uploaded content, and some members that are marked as contributors should be able to upload to this account via the vimeo api. What I am trying to achieve is that each contributing user would go through oauth authentication and use their access token to upload. This way we could see who uploaded which video.

I have been struggling to achieve this for days now. I have the upload access from Vimeo for my app, but when i would like to get an access token using the authorization code grant with the upload scope to my user I get the following error:

> This app cannot generate a token with the upload scope for the requested account. This app can only upload to the app owner's account.

Which is weird considering that is precisely what I am trying to do. If I do not give the upload scope, my upload gets rejected with 403 Forbidden stating the user does not have the upload scope.

What am I doing wrong, or what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks guys

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit what you need to do. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52475067/generating-unauthenticated-token-with-upload-scope seems like it will share why this is happening

Comment: Thanks, but I am fine with my clients going through oAuth, as a matter of fact I need them to, because I can't give everyone personal access tokens via dev. I want them to login to their vimeo account, get a token and be able to upload via api on the frontend. But for the love of it I cant give them the upload scope..